# Get the height of the softkeyboard in Adobe AIR Mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

We're trying to plan out a mobile AIR application that will deploy to both Android and iOS. One of the screens our design team has returned is a fullscreen text editor that runs from the  top of the screen to the keyboard. I obviously cannot do this if I cannot grab the height of the keyboard programatically. Is there a way to do this?

I know that it is possible in iOS and it appears to be impossible in Android. I have no issue creating an ANE to do it, but I would rather avoid it if the data is already available in AIR. Alternatively, I could just assume that the keyboard is 1/2 the size of the screen and this would work, for the most part, on iOS just fine.

In short, is getting the height of the softkeyboard possible in AIR?

Comment: Good question; I do not believe this info is exposed in any way.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. I'm surprised Apple makes it available even natively. They are overly protective of their keyboard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you can access it using the stage class. Take a look at `this.stage.softKeyboardRect` within your view.

Note: I have not tried this personally, but you may need to access it after a softkeyboard event. Add an event listener to your text input on `softKeyboardActivate`, then call `this.stage.softKeyboardRect` to get the height and position of the keyboard.

Comment: Perfect. I had never even noticed that property before. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have confirmed this works both on iOS and Android after the `SoftKeyboardEvent.ACTIVATE` event fires. Tested on iOS6 (iPad gen 1 and 3) as well as Android 4.2 (Galaxy Nexus) with default and SwiftKey keyboards

Comment: It worked perfectly on Samsung Galaxy S3 and Galaxy Tab but the height and top dimensions are all wrong on my HTC 1 (m8). Weird!

Comment: @AntoineMouquod It seems to depend on keyboard, unfortunately. I did find an ANE (from the great guys at FreshPlanet, I believe) that was built to solve this issue, so you may want to take a look at that if you need it.

Comment: @JoshJanusch thanks, it looks great! I'll try that in the next build. For now I've been using a simple hack: I'm considering the keyboard takes half of the screen and I push everything so that the selected textfield appear just on top of that. And it works. But that ane is a better solution